# R: How can I make a column with lots of categorical levels binary?

Tags: r, binary

I would like to have "ecommerce", "consumer goods" and "technology" equal 1, and all other industries equal 0. There are a ton of levels within the Industry.Vertical column, how can I make it binary?

A little piece of the dataset:

```
*Industry.Vertical*      *City..Location*
technology                Andheri
healthcare                Mumbai
luxury label              Mumbai
technology                Chembur
ecommerce                 Bengaluru
food & beverages          New Delhi
ecommerce                 Gurgaon
finance                   Bengaluru
finance                   New Delhi
waste management service  Hyderabad
technology                Bengaluru
agriculture               Nairobi
energy                    New Delhi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to check if `Industry` column has any of `c("ecommerce", "consumer goods", "technology")` values and turn them to integers.

```
df$new_col <- as.integer(df$Industry %in% c("ecommerce", "consumer goods", "technology"))
```

which is faster than using `ifelse` :

```
df$new_col <- ifelse(df$Industry %in% c("ecommerce", "consumer goods", "technology"), 1, 0)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you! Also, is there a way to make it TRUE/FALSE instead?

Comment: If you remove `as.integer` it gives you `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. Check `df$Industry %in% c("ecommerce", "consumer goods", "technology")`

Answer (score 0):

We can coerce to binary with `+`

```
df$new_col <- +(df$Industry %in% c("ecommerce", "consumer goods", "technology"))
```